# How to Identify the Base Linux Distribution of a Docker Image from its Dockerfile Using Conditional or Try-Error Statements?

Tags: linux, docker, if-statement, dockerfile, operating-system

I'm working with Docker images, and I need to determine the base Linux distribution (e.g., Debian, Alpine, Arch Linux) of a given Docker image by including code directly within its Dockerfile. I want to use conditional statements or try-error blocks to handle different scenarios.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this by parsing the Dockerfile and including the detection within the Dockerfile itself? Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
# Check for Debian
RUN if grep -q -i "debian" /etc/os-release; then \
    echo "This Docker image is based on Debian." \
;fi

# Check for Alpine
RUN if grep -q -i "alpine" /etc/os-release; then \
    echo "This Docker image is based on Alpine Linux." \
;fi

# Check for Arch Linux
RUN if grep -q -i "archlinux" /etc/os-release; then \
    echo "This Docker image is based on Arch Linux." \
;fi
```

Is there a more efficient or reliable way to accomplish this by examining the Dockerfile itself? I want to avoid false positives and ensure that the detection works for various image versions and variations in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Your image will always be built `FROM` a known image, and that will almost always have a known distribution.  Do you actually need a test like this?

Comment: No, I would like to test it after words because I will use the set package managers for it.

Comment: If your image is, say, `FROM node:lts-alpine`, you know that you have the Alpine `apk` package manager available, and not Debian's APT; why check again?